# Supported Interface Orientation and shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my project settings i made Supported Interface Orientation as both landscape.

Should i still implement below in each view controller?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: if you want to support ios < 6

Comment: in iOS 6 the methods r different thats it nothing else

Comment: @j_mcnally, so just specifying in app settings is not enough in < ios6?

Comment: right you need one of the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS < 6.x

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation // Deprecated in iOS 6.x 
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

iOS > 6.x

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

ya its better to implement and it would be better if you implement it in info.plist the orientation to landscape

for ios>6

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```